# Free/busy information from powershell?

Tags: exchange, powershell

Are there any powershell commandlets for reading free/busy information in exchange 2007/2010? I have been unable to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to do that you need to use Exchange Web Services.  There's a EWS managed API you can call from PowerShell, but it is just a library, and you need to figure out what you need to do basically yourself from documentation.

This guy does some PowerShell and EWS stuff: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com